# Django Tutorial Part 1 'Poll' object has no attribute 'was_published_today'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm doing this Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ and was_*published*_today isn't working. Thanks for your time.

Here's the command line:

```
    Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
    win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
    >>> Poll.objects.all()
    [<Poll: What's up?>]
    >>> Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
    <Poll: What's up?>
    >>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
    >>> p.was_published_today()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'Poll' object has no attribute 'was_published_today'
```

Here's models.py

```
    # Create your models here.
    from django.db import models

    import datetime

    class Poll(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question
        def was_published_today(self):
            return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()


    class Choice(models.Model):
        poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
        choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField()
        # ...
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question

    >>> dir (p)
    ['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict_
    _', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__
    ', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_e
    x__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_
    _unicode__', '__weakref__', '_base_manager', '_collect_sub_objects', '_default_m
    anager', '_deferred', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_
    get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_
    perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_set_pk_val', '_state', 'choice
    _set', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'full_clean', 'g
    et_next_by_pub_date', 'get_previous_by_pub_date', 'id', 'objects', 'pk', 'prepar
    e_database_save', 'pub_date', 'question', 'save', 'save_base', 'serializable_val
    ue', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']
```

Note: I am also using instantdjango.com 's Instant Django.

Comment: Things to try: 1) run `python manage.py shell` again, 2) delete `models.pyc` file.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and the error remained the same. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Can you do `dir(p)` and see what attributes the object has?

Comment: Done, added to the bottom of the code. 'was_published_today' isn't showing as an attribute.

Comment: check the indentation of `was_published_today` method

Comment: The indentation worked. I usually use tabs throughout and I think the example I copied and pasted with used 4 spaces.

Comment: What happens when you make `was_published_today` break (remove the colon after (self) or something else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem as I was working through the Django tutorial. I found that, in order to pick up custom methods, I had to exit from the Python shell and restart it (and re-import the Poll class).